# Good Stripes tutorials / examples?

Tags: java, stripes

The company I just started working for is using [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) for parts of its web page development these days, and while it seems to be a nice enough web framework it no one really uses it-- it is almost non existent on the 'net. It's not even first in it's [google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=stripes&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and the result you **do** get is for its old home page.

So, do any of you people use Stripes? Of your own volition? Do you know of any good tutorials / examples?

Comment: I think the reason you don't see much about it on the net is because it's so simple to use. Check the mailing list, or drop by the irc channel if you want to see how active the community around it is. #stripes on freenode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used (or even heard of) Stripes.

Regardless, there's a book from [The Pragmatic Bookshelf](http://www.pragprog.com/) called [Stripes: ...and Java web development is fun again](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fdstr/stripes) that may be worth checking out. You could also check out the Stripes [mailing list archive](https://sourceforge.net/mail/?group_id=145476).

Comment: why do you answer if you never used ( or even heard of ) Stripes?

Comment: I answered because I'm good at Google. It is a good answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 9):

I recommend checking out the book referenced by jko:

> a book from The Pragmatic Bookshelf called [Stripes: ...and Java web development is fun again](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/fdstr/stripes)

Whilst still in 'beta' the book covers everything very well.

Another good place to start is [this ONJava article](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/01/24/java-web-development-with-stripes.html).

I have used Stripes on a few projects now and have liked it a lot.

It may sound crazy but the Stripes quickstart and sample application documentation on [the website](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Sample+Application) does a pretty good job of covering the bases.

This is helped by the fact there is little to Stripes, probably because it is relatively new and not trying to be all things to all people. I would say give the quick-start a try and if by the end of it you are unsatisfied look elsewhere. At the end of the day you and your company have to be happy (and productive) with what you are using irrespective of how many people are using it.

Answer (score 3):

It's a shame that some people perceive Stripes as a framework for which "there really just isn't much support or information for it." In reality, the Stripes community is **very** supportive - have a look at the [mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.stripes.user) and you'll see how friendly and responsive people are. In fact, some have said on the #stripes IRC channel that they have had better response for Hibernate-related questions than on #hibernate itself!

Give Stripes a good, serious look instead of dismissing it because of misconceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Stripes is a great framework. We converted a major project from a home grown framework to stripes and it took less than one week.

The book referenced above is a great resources, as is the mailing list.
There's also an active irc channel #stripes on freenode.

It's a very powerful framework that doesn't get in your way.

Answer (score 0):

We considered it when we were looking at open source frameworks. But we saw the same thing your did that there really just isn't much support or information for it. You should always weight the community support factor surrounding open source projects before picking one. (which is what you are doing here)